# when i refresh the page the text removes by itself , php?

Tags: php, mysql, post

When I type something in a text box and save it in mysqli it works perfectly but when I refresh that same page the text that i wrote stuff, it disappears for no reason. I also I have another text box in that page and it works perfectly fine. How can I fix that? The bio text box is the one I'm having issues.

```
    $getpro = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'  "));$pro = $getpro;
$bios = $pro["bios"];
$realtionship = $pro["realtionship"];
$impmessage = $pro["impmessage"];
if ($_POST['bio']){
$bio = $_POST['bio'] ;
$query;
}
if ($_POST['impmessage']){
$impmessage = $_POST['impmessage'] ;
$query;
}
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE `profile` SET  bios ='$bio',  impmessage = '$impmessage' WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'");<form name="bio"action="" method="post">
<p>Important Message</p> <textarea   cols="50" style="resize:none" name="bio"  rows="7" ><? echo $bios; ?></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="change">
</form><hr /><form name="impmessage"action="" method="post">
<p>Important Message</p> <textarea   cols="50" style="resize:none" name="impmessage"  rows="7" ><? echo $impmessage; ?></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="change">
</form>
```

Comment: take a look at mysql injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and ways to protect against it, specially at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Escaping

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rearranged & removed some of the code and tried tidying it a bit:

```
<?php
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) // if form is submitted using POST method
    {
        if ( isset( $_POST['bio'] ) ){
            $bio = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['bio'] ); // escape special characters is user input
            $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `profile` SET  bios ='$bio' WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'"); //update bios
        }

        if (isset( $_POST['impmessage'] ) ){
            $impmessage = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['impmessage'] ); // escape special characters is user input
            $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `profile` SET impmessage = '$impmessage' WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'"); //update impmessage
        }
    }

    $pro = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'  "));
?>

<form name="bio" action="" method="post">
    <p>Bios</p>
    <textarea cols="50" style="resize:none" name="bio" id="bio" rows="7" ><?php echo $pro["bios"]; ?></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="change">
</form>
<hr />
<form name="impmessage" action="" method="post">
    <p>Important Message</p>
    <textarea cols="50" style="resize:none" name="impmessage" id="impmessage" rows="7" ><?php echo $pro["impmessage"]; ?></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="change">
</form>
```

Some notes for you:

- First of all avoid mysql_* functions. Instead use mysqli or PDO
- I would always prefer writing the code for processing of user inputs in the very beginning of the page, ie. before outputting anything. Because, if the user inputs makes any changes on the output, it would easily display the updates since we are doing the processing before outputting anything. So, when we query the db, it would fetch the updated data. Also, if we wanted to redirect to another page or have to send some other headers to the browser, we could do it, as the headers should always be sent before outputting anything.
- Another thing is, always escape user inputs. Otherwise, prone to sql injections. Best thing would be to use prepared statements which is available in mysqli & PDO.
- When you name `id` of elements in your HTML, make sure that it is unique. Because no same ids could occur twice. But class names can occur for any number of times.
- Also make sure that your PHP code doesn't get mixed up with the HTML. Properly enclose the PHP code with the `<?php` & `?>` tags. I would always prefer avoiding shorthands.
- Since you are using two forms, both the input won't reach the server side. Only a single one. If you wanted to both inputs to be reached at the same time, then use a single form.
- I have also avoided unwanted assignment operations from the fetched data, to other variables.
- Also, you should always properly indent your code for better readability.

I hope this would help. Wish you good luck. :)

Comment: sweet it works, thanks may i ask whats the different between mysql_* and PDO

Comment: Another thing I would like to let you know is, make sure that you accept ANSWERS for the questions that you ask in StackOverflow. ie, you have asked 7 questions in total so far, out of which only for 1 question you have accepted an answer. If you don't accept answers, then it would affect the amount of help you'll get from here. To accept an answer for a questions you have asked here, click on the TickMark icon(check mark) near to the solution that you feel as the best one. That's all! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running your update query every page load. If the post value isn't filled and you refresh it's going to update with empty values. 
Ps sberry is right lots of other things to fix before this goes production.

Comment: i know. i know i need to add the sql injection  but ima create a function for that so right now im not worry about that. Do you know how to stop that? The strange thing the $impmessage is working perfectly fine, like when i refresh it. it does gave me a blank text back.

Comment: One way would be put a your update query in a condition. 
Eg. if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")  {// put your query here } I think the reason why one form works is that your browser is resubmitting that last form each time. Get rid of the second form this is only going to cause you problems.

Comment: i read online, its possible for a page could have 2 forms [link](http://bavotasan.com/2009/processing-multiple-forms-on-one-page-with-php/#comments). maybe I might be doing something wrong.